# Process ID of an Activity in android?

Tags: android, process

Can i get the process Id of an messaging activity? and also using this can i start that particular activity.

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking for Messaging Intent not process id.

Eg: startActivity(com.android.mms)

Comment: What i exactly want is the messaging Activity button click??

Answer (score 0):

One solution that isn't pretty is to use Activity manager and go through all the Running app processes searching for that messaging app.

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = manager
                .getRunningAppProcesses();

        for (RunningAppProcessInfo process : processes) {
                String name = process.processName;
                if (name.contains(MESSAGING_APP_NAME) {
                    return process.pid;
                }
        }
```